# scroll() in not working in jQuery for dynamic elements

Tags: jquery, scroll

I am using the following.This is not working for dynamically created elements.I am usinh jQuery 1.4.2

```
 $(".wrapper1").live("scroll",function(){
     alert(123);
    $(".wrapper2")
    .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
  });
```

This is also not working for normal elements also.(Which are loaded while the page loading)

What might be the reason here .Please help me.Thanks in advance....

Comment: Any reason why you use this obsolete version ? I know I wouldn't manage a version not made for today browsers and full of bugs fixed in new versions.

Comment: because in my project a already used that.

Comment: any version no problem for me

Comment: @PSR suggestion `live` is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/) use `on` or `delegate`.

Comment: @dystroy i solved my problem by using 1.9.1 version.Thank u

Comment: @karthick.k i used 1.4 version.In that version on is not supported

Comment: @dystroy what is the reason for live it is not working

Comment: @karthick.k It's not deprecated in the latest version, it's been removed entirely. However, in the version they said they're using, `.live()` isn't deprecated.

Answer (score 8):

Browsers change, jQuery bugs are fixed, that's two reasons why it's important to always use a recent version of jQuery (after due tests, you can't just point to latest).

Your code, adapted to jQuery 1.9, would be, for another event type,

```
$(document).on("event_type",".wrapper1", function(){
    $(".wrapper2")
        .scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
});
```

The reason to use `$(document)` as receiver and not `$(".wrapper1")` is that only the elements existing at binding time would receive and delegate the events. `on` doesn't work like the old `live`.

Except that this won't work for `scroll` events as they don't bubble.

So the most reasonnable solution I can propose would be to define a function :

```
$.fn.bindScrollHandler1 = function(){
    $(this).on('scroll', function(){
       $(".wrapper2").scrollLeft($(".wrapper1").scrollLeft());
    });
}
```

and call it at start :

```
$('.wrapper1').bindScrollHandler1();
```

and each time you create a new .wrapper1 element :

```
myNewElement.bindScrollHandler1();
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/8JUYy/)

Note that your complete logic seems a little lacking, as you don't pair the scrollbars but make them all work the same.

Comment: I edited with a solution which isn't pretty but the best I see now.

Answer (score 2):

I know that you solved your problem (or you think you solved it), but if you have some problems you should know:

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to `.on()`.

This is from the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/).

There are 2 ways to use the `.on()` function:

1. `$('selector').on('event', function () { body of the handler });`

   The event handler is directly attached to the matched elements. Since it's done imperatively, the selector is resolved and all the matched elements get an attached event handler. It's the same as calling `$('.asdf').click()` for example.
2. `$('selector1').on('event', 'selector2', function () { handler });`

   As you can see there is 2 selectors: The event handler will be attached to selector1, but it will handle the events fired on selector2! This is very much like `.live()` or `.delegate()`, (actually it's exactly the same).

   What `.live()` does is it attaches the event handler to 'document', and handles the events of the elements matched by the selector (it's the same as `$('document').on('event', 'selector', function() {});`).

   The benefit of this is that the event handler is attached to an already existing element and that will be able to handle the events of dynamically created elements through event bubbling.

   So in your case the second syntax seems to be what you need.

**EDIT**: There is a big problem with this I was not aware of: the scroll element is not bubbling. There are workarounds, but I have no time to write a solution now. Let me get back at it, when I return in about a few hours. Or if dystroy's solution is working, please don't hesitate to accept it.

Comment: No : as the scroll event doesn't bubble, you can't delegate it to dynamically added elements.

Comment: It's a little more difficult than I thought. Try dystroy's solution. @dystroy: you are right.

Comment: @SoonDead I was surprised like you at first. There might be a better solution but I don't see it.

Answer (score 0):

In my app, I have a button that appends form fieldsets to the body every time a button is clicked - I wanted to scroll the page down to the new element, but that didn't work for obvious reasons (bubbling, etc.).  I came up with a simple fix...

```
function scroll(pixels){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: pixels
    }, 1000);
};

function addObservation(x){
    $('body').append(x);
    newFieldSet = $('fieldset').last();
    pixelsFromTop = newFieldSet.offset().top;
    scroll(pixelsFromTop);
};

$(document).on("click", "#add_observation", function(){
    addObservation("<fieldset>SOME FORM FIELDS HERE</fieldset>");
});
```

So every time you add a fieldset, `.offset().top` measures how many pixels the fieldset is from the top and then scrolls the window that distance.  In your case, you could do `pixelsFromLeft = newFieldSet.offset().left` and replace `scrollTop` with `scrollLeft`, or something to that effect.

Answer (score 0):

No difference in dynamically generated elements, this code works for me:

```
$('#div1').scrollTop($('#div1')[0].scrollHeight);
```

In this HTML:

```
<div id="div1">
    <div id="dynamicallyGeneratedDiv1"></div>
    <div id="dynamicallyGeneratedDiv2"></div>
</div>
```

No matter how many "dynamicallyGeneratedDiv" you insert into "div1", it will automatically scroll down to the bottom of "div1".