# How to use jQuery.bind on dynamically created items

Tags: jquery

I have this:

```
$(".sf_sub_accordian, .sf_find_container").bind("click", function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

But it stops working when I add content dynamically via ajax-call.

How to make `bind` work with dynamically created content?

**Edit**: Without success I have already tried this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".sf_sub_accordian, .sf_find_container",function(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
});
```

In fact, it doesn't work at all if I do it like that.

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16058402/dynamic-created-content-is-not-binding-jquery-events

Comment: `$(document).on("click", ".sf_sub_accordian, .sf_find_container",function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});`

Comment: @PedroCorcheroMurga: I've seen those answers already and tried that. jquery.on() doesn't work. Propagation is not stopped.