# preventDefault not working on anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to log the click on an anchor that's being generated asynchronously.

The asynchronous call - which works perfectly fine - looks like this:

```
 $("#txt_search").keyup(function() {
    var search = $("#txt_search").val();

    if (search.length > 0)
    {
      $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        url: "<?php echo site_url ('members/searchmember') ;?>",
        data:'search=' + search,
      success: function(msg){
        $('#search_results').html("");
        var obj = JSON.parse(msg);

        if (obj.length > 0)
        {
          try
          {
            var items=[];   
            $.each(obj, function(i,val){                      
                items.push($('<li class="search_result" />').html(
                  '<img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>' + val.userImage + ' " /><a class="user_name" href="" rel="' + val.userId + '">'
                  + val.userFirstName + ' ' + val.userLastName 
                  + ' (' + val.userEmail + ')</a>'
                  )
                );
            }); 
            $('#search_results').append.apply($('#search_results'), items);
          } 
          catch(e) 
          {   
            alert(e);
          }   
        }
        else
        {
          $('#search_results').html($('<li/>').text('This user does not have an account yet'));   
        }   

      },
      error: function(){            
        alert('The connection is lost');
      }
      });
    }
  });
```

The anchor I want to get to is `<a class="user_name" href="" rel="' + val.userId + '">' + val.userFirstName + ' ' + val.userLastName + ' (' + val.userEmail + ')</a>'`

I detect the click on these anchors with this function:

```
  // click op search results
  $("a.user_name").on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
  });
```

The problem seems to be that the `preventDefault` is not doing anything... I've looked at most of the questions involving this problem on Stackoverflow and checked jQuery's own documentation on the topic, but I can't seem to find what's wrong. I've tried adding a `async: false` statement to the AJAX-call, because perhaps the asynchronous call might be the problem, but that didn't fix it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Event does not bind with dynamically added element unless you delegate it to parent element or document using [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/). You have to use different form of on for event delegation.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.user_name', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

#### delegated events

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event
>   handler, as described next.
>
> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to 
>   frequently attach and remove event handlers, [Reference](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: Genius, thanks for this, was trying to stop the anchor from putting its href (hash) into the url so sammy.js wouldn't pick it up - success :)

Comment: yes use this if your element is generating dynamically.

Answer (score 6):

The `.on()` syntax you showed will only bind handlers to elements that match the selector *at that moment* - not to elements added in the future. Try this instead:

```
$("#search_results").on("click", "a.user_name", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); 
});
```

This binds a handler to the parent element, and then when a click occurs jQuery only calls your callback function if the actual target element matches the selector in `.on()`'s second parameter at the time of the click. So it works for dynamically added elements (as long as the *parent* exists at the time the above runs).

Comment: I just got forgot to use thus method while the elements are dynamically generated.

Answer (score 4):

This should work for you -

```
$('.search_result').on('click', 'a.user_name', function(){
    // your code here
    // code
    return false;   
});
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 $("a.user_name").on('click', function(e) {
    return false;
  });
```

or

```
  $(document).on('click', 'a.user_name', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault(); 
          });
```

[**Difference between .on() functions calls**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057640/difference-between-on-functions-calls)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and it turned out my selector was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

May be your a href linked with other listeners too. Check with **event.preventDefault
event.stopImmediatePropagation();** 
together.
You can check this site for more info
https://codeplanet.io/preventdefault-vs-stoppropagation-vs-stopimmediatepropagation/