# usage of jquery : $(document).on()

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use jquery `.on()` to do the AJAX

Anyway,I test two method below,both of them works
I want to know what's the difference between them??
are the both method correct?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/*method 1*/
/*$(document).on('submit', '.login-form', function(){ */
$(document).on('click', '.searchtitle', function(){
    ttest = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(ttest);    
});
/*method 2*/
$(".searchtitle").on('click',   function(){
    ttest = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(ttest);    
});
</script>

test.html
<form action="" method="post"  class="searchtitle">
    {% csrf_token %}
    search activity :<input type="text" name="title">
    <button type="button" class="btn .btn-sm btn-success" id="search">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057640/difference-between-on-functions-calls

Comment: Reading documentation also (usually) helps: https://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one is called **event delegation**, if your `.searchtitle` elements added to DOM **later**,

- the first one will work (new added elements have event handlers).

  ```js
  $('body').on('click', 'p', function (e) {
      $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
  });

  $('button').on('click', function () {
      $('<p></p>').html('Hello').prependTo('body');
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>

  <button>Add Element</button>
  ```
- but the second one won't (new added elements doesn't have any event handler).

  ```js
  $('p').on('click', function (e) {
      $(this).css('background', 'yellow');
  });

  $('button').on('click', function () {
      $('<p></p>').html('Hello').prependTo('body');
  });
  ```

  ```html
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <p>Hello</p>
  <p>Hello</p>

  <button>Add Element</button>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Method two is better for performance reason since you limit the scope of the checking that needs to happen every time there is a button click.

The first approach is no more performant than the now deprecated `live` delegate, but necessary if you can't narrow the scope of the region that needs to be monitored for click events.

Answer (score 0):

#### Case - 1

```
/*method 1*/
$(document).on('submit', '.login-form', function(){
    ttest = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(ttest);    
});
```

This is event delegation. Where you trigger it on submit of everything on the document, and check whether the target was having a class, `.login-form`, then do the rest.

You can read more about [**event delegation in jquery here**](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/).

#### Case - 2

```
/*method 2*/
$(".searchtitle").on('click',   function(){
    ttest = $(this).serialize();
    console.log(ttest);    
});
```

This is attaching an event to a particular DOM element. It wont trigger on all the submits on the document. But only for the particular element.